# Geocoder - How to use near query with multiple points?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, google-geocoder, rails-geocoder, geocoder

I have one model Store, Every store has its radious limit for delivery.

For an example,

> Store 1 can delivery within 10 miles
>
> Store 2 can delivery within 30 miles

So i have diffrent points for every store,
In past i was used below query to find out store withing a specific range

```
@stores = Store.near([latitude, longitude], 100, :order => false)
```

I don't have specific range now, How can i do query for multiple points of stores ?
Any help or suggestion will be appreciated to overcome this issue .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution i need to pass database column name to get correct result with below query

```
Store.near([latitude, longitude], :delivery_within)
```

**`delivery_within` is database column which is in stores table.**